# Restarting app changes SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Alright, I have a list of numbers I have to save, and I seperate those with line breaks ("\n) and then put them into a string to save:

```
        List<String> usedTabs = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        StringBuilder save = new StringBuilder();
        if(usedTabs.size()==0) {
            save = new StringBuilder("0");
        } else {
            for(String s: usedTabs) {
                save.append(s);
                save.append("\n");
            }
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("saveUsedTabs", save.toString());
        editor.commit();
```

Great, this works! Too get back my list when I need it again I do this:

```
    String save = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString("saveUsedTabs", "0");
    String tabs[] = save.split("\n");
    usedTabs.addAll(Arrays.asList(tabs));
```

Works too. But if I restart the app after saving, when I load this again after the last \n there are some 4spaces: `"6\n3\n5\n3\n3\n    "`

How does this even happen? I already changed the key to make sure my preference isn't being used by anything else.

Comment: The space might be there in the string. You can use trim() to remove the extra spaces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to store your string data in Shared preference.
If you are in activity then,

```
getSharedPreference("name of your preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("key", "value").apply(); //use .commit() or apply() at the end.
```

If you are in other class then, just add context at the beginning.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> usedTabs = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    StringBuilder save = new StringBuilder();
    if(usedTabs.size()==0) {
        save = new StringBuilder("0");
    } else {
        for(String s: usedTabs) {
            save.append(s);
            save.append("\n");
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("saveUsedTabs", save.toString().replaceAll(" ",""));
    editor.commit();
```

Try the above, just remove the white spaces while you are storing the value.